# Change table so that it returns different results for unordered queries

Tags: sql-server

We had a query that returned the top 1 row from a table.  Any of the results that matched the where clause would do so that was fine.  Now we need to make the query determinate, it still doesn't matter which row is returned but it should the same one, previously it *almost* always returned the same row.

So I added an order by clause and it seems to work fine.  My question is about testing the change. I want to be able to change the table so that it *would* return different values if the `order by` wasn't there.

I've done a

```
Alter table TableName rebuild
```

and I assume that would have caused this effect but now I've done it once I don't know any other ways.

Comment: *"previously it almost always returned the same row"* Sounds like you had a `TOP 1` without an `ORDER BY`. Add an `ORDER BY` always get a reliably result, `TOP 1` without an `ORDER BY` means that SQL Server is free to return *any* arbitrary row from the database.

Comment: All that you're guaranteed without an `ORDER BY` clause is *arbitrariness*, not *randomness*, as you've already experienced.

Comment: @Larnu - have you read their question? They've said they've already added an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: But they didn't **previously** @Damien_The_Unbeliever . Your comment is saying exactly what I am; `ORDER BY` means that the results will be consistant, no `ORDER BY` means that won't be.

Comment: Thanks I need a way to increase the chance that it would produce a different arbitrary result so my tester can verify that the order by fix stops it being arbitary.

Comment: Why does a tester need to verify [Documented behaviour](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)? "Otherwise, TOP returns the first N number of rows in an undefined order".

Comment: The point in my previous comment being that you probably don't have testers verify every aspect of the languages you rely upon to do your work. You instead trust the *implementers* of those languages to have their own suite of tests, and yes, to produce documentation that states what you can and cannot rely upon.

Comment: Hi @Damien_The_Unbeliever well sure but the tester has a bug report that says that sometimes the results are different. I have a fix that I believe fixes the issue. I could ask them to keep testing for x hours to see if the error turns up but they'd like to force the issue to appear on the unfixed system and not appear on the fixed one.

Comment: Without hacking into the table / code, the short answer is no. You might be able to make the problem repeat more often by changing the indexing (esp the clustered index), but that sort of thing is problematic since it has much wider effects. That approach also needs to be crafted to that specific piece of code and the current design of the tables involved. And they would obviously need to be done carefully and temporarily and for this one specific test.